# Is returning List<T> from method differ in performance from returning Collection<T>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, collections

We have a web project that contain its business methods in a class library project called "Bll.dll"
some methods of Bll.dll return List<> ...
from a source - that i don't remember now - told  that returning Collection<> is better than returning List<>
**Is it a valid ?**
Note that i don't make any process on values returned from BLL methods .. just view it in a web page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Collection<T>` is implemented, IIRC, as a wrapper around an `IList<T>`, of which the default implementation is `List<T>`. Therefore a `Collection<T>` has at least one more abstraction than a `List<T>`, but in general this won't be a bottleneck. In fact, you might consider returning `IList<T>`.

Edit: here is the constructor of `Collection<T>`, courtesy of reflector:

```
public Collection()
{
    this.items = new List<T>();
}
```

so indeed, this wraps a layer of abstraction. The *plus* side of this is that you can add your own validation etc by subclassing `Collection<T>` (which is not possible when using `List<T>` directly or via subclassing, since there are no interesting `virtual` methods).

The other thing to consider is that they will have the same *overall* performance in terms of "O" (assuming you use the default `List<T>` implementation). Indexer lookup will be `O(1)`, etc

Comment: what you mean by IIRC ? and did you see IList<T> is the best in my case ?

Comment: See http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/IIRC; and yes, unless you have a specific need to use a concrete return type, `IList<T>` is a good choice - it gives you the flexibility to use any implementation without the client having to know about it. So you can **expose** it as `IList<T>`, but return `List<T>` for now, with the freedom to substitute anything else (`Collection<T>`, `MyCustomFooCollection`, etc) later.

Answer (score 2):

You really should only return the interface that meets the goals you set when designing your API. For example if you only expect your clients to iterate over a collection then return `IEnumerable<T>`. As to your specific question I feel `ICollection<T>` is kind of useless as it lacks an indexer.

Comment: How do you know the client only wants to iterate over the collection? Maybe they want to use it as a collection. Or perhaps just get the count. What if you later want to expose additional properties? Microsoft's Framework Design Guidelines recommend the exact opposite for these and other reasons.

Comment: @Jonathon - Part of the problem with bloated frameworks is that the designers try and cover all use cases poorly instead of focusing on one thing well. Feel free to follow along the Microsoft guidelines blindly if you wish.

Comment: If you have an Collection<T> anyways, you do nothing to reduce bloat by only offering you client an IEnumerable. In fact you increase blost because now they have to either create their own collection or detect that you gave them one and cast it.

Answer (score 0):

That better may not apply to the performace but only to type of the returning type.

In this case is not easy to say what is better, in my opinion that depend of the usage of method "localy" is beter to return type that we operate on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with returning a List is that the caller can modify it. If you would ever like to wire up some notification mechanism ("Notify the callee whenever the caller adds a new object to it"), you can't as a List is a dead end.

Returning a Collection/ICollection allows you to create your own implementation that has whatever you want.

Basically, a List means that you're stuck in a corner that you can't escape without a breaking change.

So Collection/ICollection/IList is preferable.

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387937/why-is-it-considered-bad-to-expose-listt) and [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kcwalina/why-we-dont-recommend-using-listt-in-public-apis).

Comment: You can return AsReadOnly of the List<T>, which is an IList<T>. Of course, this thin wrapper will probably have some trivial amount of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is expose a strongly typed class like CustomerCollection. That way you have a place to add properties and methods later.

Offically you shouldn't expose a List, but I personally see no problem with it.

Comment: Well CustomerCollection would inherit from ObjectModel.Collection<T>. As for List, the only version I'm aware of is List<T>.

Comment: Well, you'd have to explicitly declare a CustomerCollection, deriving it from Collection<T>, but I'm not sure what that buys you over returning IList<T>.

Comment: What if you later want to add a "TotalDollarsSpent" property to the collection itself? You can't do that to an IList<T>.

Comment: That's true, but it's also true that I wouldn't want to.  The total is a derived value.

Comment: If you use total a lot you can make it a read-only property that encapsulates the operation.