# Rhino Mocks: Instantiating Mock property so Expectation can reference it

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I'm writing a unit test with a mock and I'm having trouble writing it successfully. One of the properties is a collection and I need to reference it when setting an expectation for the mock. Right now the expectation statement throws a null. Here's what it roughly looks like.

```
IFoo myMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IFoo>();
List<Entity> col = new List<Entity>();
Entity entity = new Entity();

myMock.Expect(p => p.FooCollection).Return(col);
myMock.Expect(p => p.FooCollection.Add(entity)); // throws null exception here
```

I'm new to rhino mocks and have a feeling I'm not doing this correctly. Is there anyway else to properly instantiate the collection? Possibly without an expectation like I have above?

**Update**
I think I'm having the problem because the interface I defined specifies the collection as readonly.

```
interface IFoo
{
    List<Entity> FooCollection { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not overly familiar with Rhino Mocks, but I think your expectations aren't *actually* hooked up until you call `.Replay()` - the mocking methodology you hint at in your example looks more like [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) to me.

That said, I think you're doing something more fundamentally wrong here. Exactly what is it that you want to test? Is it the `p` object, or something on `List<Entity>`? If what you actually want to test is that `p.YourMethodUnderTest()` actually adds `entity` to the collection, you probably just want to setup `p.FooCollection` to return your list, and then verify that your list contains the entity object.

```
// Arrange
IFoo myMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IFoo>();
List<Entity> col = new List<Entity>();
Entity entity = new Entity();

myMock.Expect(p => p.FooCollection).Return(col);
// myMock.Expect(p => p.FooCollection.Add(entity)) - skip this

// Act
p.YourMethodUnderTest(entity);

// Assert
Assert.IsTrue(col.Contains(entity)); // Or something like that
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of that! I think I was asking too much from rhino mocks. Thanks so much for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mocks you should use stubs, like:

```
IFoo myMock = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IFoo>();
myMock.FooCollection = col;
```

Also, you are setting the expectation on a real object (collection.Add()), which won't really work. You can solve this by making your `FooCollection` property type of `IList` instead of a concrete `List`.

Using concrete collection types as parameters is a code smell anyway (and I suggest using FxCop to teach you such things).

Comment: The collection is readonly so you can't directly assign it like you did in your example. Is it a code smell because I expose the collection as a property? I could see keeping it a private field and adding an AddEntity() method as beneficial because now that I look back at my code, there is coupled code where the client code does things with the entity after it is added to the collection.

Comment: You're right about the read-only collection, my code would not work. As for the code smell, I meant this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387937/why-is-it-considered-bad-to-expose-listt

Comment: I'm not sure I totally agree with the dominant answers for that question but I do think I needed to keep from exposing my collection. The answers mentioned that List<T> is bloated and IList<T> is not so bloated. Well, yeah that's how it should be. Your IList<T> variable still points to a List<T>, so it's not less "bloated".

Comment: By exposing `IList<>` you are actually making it easier for an implementation to use something other than `List<>` - like `Entity[]` array, for example. The idea is to use interface to define contracts, and not to enforce implementation details in these contracts. Specifying a concrete collection type (like `List`) is enforcing an implementation detail without the real need. And by using interfaces you are actually making it easier to mock things.

Comment: As for your suggestion on `AddEntity()` method instead of exposing the collection, it's a good suggestion. See Law of Demeter (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

Comment: Thanks for your perspective. I think I grew a little more as a developer yesterday :)