# Return results from a method returning values of a query in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

This is my code in a controller; im using MVC 5 ASP.NET

```
var x = db.MyEntity.Include(ds => ds.MyEntity1)
    .Where(ds =>
            (
                ds.MyEntity1.MyEntity12.x <= MyEntity1.MyEntity12.x
            &&
                ds.MyEntity1.MyEntity12.y>= MyEntity1.MyEntity12.x
            )
        ||
            (
                ds.MyEntity1.MyEntity12.x<= MyEntity1.MyEntity12.y
            &&
                ds.MyEntity1.MyEntity12.y>= MyEntity1.MyEntity12.y
            ))
    .Select(ds => ds.Emp);

    var finalEmp = db.Emp.Except(x).ToList();
```

Now i want to reuse this x variable. I want to separate it into a method and call it from anywhere. But I'm having doubts what kind of a return value i should use in that method, so it will work with Except().

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, maybe of being a novice in C# and ASP.NET, i couldn't work out with answers given by banavalikar.
To be exact return type for the above method should be a `IQueryable`. However, because of the way this project is structured, this method is called from a different project. Therefore, it gave me `in different context` error. But, at the end I found a simple workaround to suite my need;
Just returning a List of strings. (My EmpIds are strings) And using `Contains()` instead `Except()`

```
public static List<string> GetNotAvailEmp(Entity1 entityx)
    {
        using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var x = db.MyEntity.Include(ds => ds.MyEntity1)
                .Where(ds =>
                    (
                      ds.MyEntity1.MyEntity12.x <= entityx.MyEntity12.x
                        &&
                      ds.MyEntity1.MyEntity12.y>= entityx.MyEntity12.x
                    )
                    ||
                    (
                     ds.MyEntity1.MyEntity12.x<= entityx.MyEntity12.y
                       &&
                     ds.MyEntity1.MyEntity12.y>= entityx.MyEntity12.y
                    ))
                   .Select(ds => ds.Emp.EmpId).ToList();
            return x;
        }
    }
```

And calling this from my controller;

```
List<string> x = MyDbQueryFile.GetNotAvailEmp(entityx);

var finalEmp= db.Emp.Where(s => !x.Contains(s.EmpId)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use IList.

Usually it is better to expose your custom objects via interfaces. This has been discussed here as well: [Why is it considered bad to expose List<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387937/why-is-it-considered-bad-to-expose-listt)

Comment: No i can't use that. I get `Error 3 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<MyDomain.Emp>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<MyDomain.Emp>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) `

Comment: tried that too `Unable to create a constant value of type 'MyDomain.Emp'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.` List wont work with except it seems. let me try Contains()?

Comment: Use IEqualityComparer as shown here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx

Comment: isn't there any other simple way i could achieve this?

Comment: Define:  
 public static IEnumerable<TSource> Except<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, IEnumerable<TSource> destination, Func<TSource, TSource, bool> comparer) 
 { 
  return source.Where(x => destination.Count(y => comparer(x, y)) == 0); 
 }   

Then call it as:  
IList<MyDomain.Emp> final = source.Except(destination, (x, y) => x.<your_unique_id> == y.<your_unique_id>).ToList();