# Class design - properties default value

Tags: c#, .net, class

Just wondering what the recommended way of tackling this scenario is and why it's better one way or another.

Let's say you have a class that represents a football team, you probably have something similar to this (oversimplified version of course):

```
public class FootballTeam
{
    public FootballTeam(string name, Person owner)
    {
        Name = name;
        Owner = owner;
    }

    public string Name {get;}

    public Person Trainer {get; set;}

    public Person Owner {get; set;}

    public List<Person> Roster {get; set;}
}
```

Now, we could argue that even a team with no players still has a roster, only it's an empty roster (as oppose to a non-existing roster).

So it would maybe make more sense to declare the `Roster` like this:

```
public List<Person> Roster {get; set;} = new List<Person>();
```

But this still suffers from a problem in my opinion:

Because `Roster` still has a setter, it does nothing to prevent it from being set to `null`, which also makes it easy to wrongly *assume* that it can never be `null`.

So instead `Roster` should look like this:

```
public List<Person> Roster {get;} = new List<Person>();
```

So now we're semantically correct in the sense that a team always has a roster, only sometimes the roster contains no players. And we simplify things for the caller in the sense that they don't have to worry about null references.

But in doing so we lost the ability to easily replace the complete existing roster with another one we already had, we're bound to that instance which we have to add/remove/clear `Persons` from, if we have two teams with the same players checking their `Rosters` for equality will return `false`, etc.

So a couple of questions:

1. What would be the best way to tackle this? Hiding the `List<Person>` and presenting forwarding methods to indirectly interact with it seems overkill and of little added bonus. Removing the setter removes some simplicity and functionality, allowing the `Roster` to be `null` seems even worse to me.
2. Assuming that the answer to 1. involves assigning a default value to the `Roster` property, are there any best practices as to where to do this? i.e., directly at the property like on the examples above or on the constructor?
3. You could also argue that a team must always have an `Owner` as well, although it does not necessarily need to always have a `Trainer`. How would you handle this as well? Forwarding methods or checking if `value == null` on the setter and if so `throw`?

Comment: I can´t see why someone would replace the entire team at once, so this seems like a strange use-case to me and thus a get-only property should be fine. However you still could achieve this using `Clear` and `AddeRange`. Anyway I assume your answer will have a high amount of opinion-based aspects making this hard - if not **impossible** - to answer *correctly*.

Comment: By exposing the list, you do off course let someone `Clear` and `AddRange` and anything else to manipulate the contents - do you *want* that to happen? Does the team not have any logic that say, should apply when new players are added or removed?

Comment: @HimBromBeere think outside the box, the roster is just an example but the question goes beyond that, it's more about when you have a class that includes a `List<T>` where the list *should* always contain something, but there may be added benefit from allowing the consumer to set it.

Comment: You should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387937/why-is-it-considered-bad-to-expose-listt

Comment: Basically, you usually want to decide "*who owns the list*?" Is it the team or something else? If something else owns it, why does team store it's own direct reference to it at all? And if the team owns it, why does it want to allow others to e.g. set it to `null`, breaking its own supposed invariants?

Comment: Well, not all lists *are* identical, a roster is pretty sure different from a shopping trolley which you empty at once regularly. We can´t answer all possible scenarios here, it completely depends on your use-case. Having said this your question is either opinion-based or too broad.

Comment: @HimBromBeere that question is also an interesting in the sense that both you and Damien_The_Unbeliever pointed out that a `List` already has `AddRange`, but if I were to expose an `IList` then that's gone, making it even harder for the consumer.

Comment: Again: ask yourself which functionality you need on a list (index based, iterating, adding, clearing, ...), or if you even **need to expose** the list. We can´t answer that, we can give you just a few ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If team "owns" the list, I would expect to see something like this:

```
public class FootballTeam
{
    private readonly List<Person> _roster = new List<Person>();
    public FootballTeam(string name, Person owner)
    {
        Name = name;
        Owner = owner;
    }

    public string Name {get;}

    public Person Trainer {get; set;}

    public Person Owner {get; set;}

    public IEnumerable<Person> Roster => _roster.AsReadOnly();

    public void AddPlayer(Person player) {
       _roster.Add(player);
       //Other logic
    }

    public void RemovePlayer(Person player) {
       //What if the player isn't on our roster?
       //Other logic?
       _roster.Remove(player);
    }

    public void ReplaceRoster(IEnumerable<Person> players) {
       _roster.Clear();
       _roster.AddRange(players);
    }
}
```

I wouldn't normally have added the `ReplaceRoster` method but apparently that's one of your use cases. Note the fact that we're using a `List` is now *encapsulated* and we've moved *up* a semantic level in the methods that our class supports.

Other methods within our class can rely on `_roster` being non-null. Consumers of our class can always rely on getting the `IEnumerable<Person>` even when the roster is empty.

If the team doesn't "own" the list, I wouldn't expect it to have the property at all.

Comment: Why have `Roster` return `IEnumerable<Person>` instead of `IReadOnlyCollection<Person>`? Is there a reason behind it?

Comment: I usually prefer `IEnumerable<Whatever>` for the properties because it's straight into LINQ-world. I may not always want to be constrained on what I'm using for my backing store, `IEnumerable<Whatever>` is the most I want to promise to consumers at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private List<Person> _roster = new List<Person>();
public List<Person> Roster {get=>_roster; set=>_roster = value ?? new List<Person>();}
```

This will prevent from assigning null to _roster.